# Is the cosmic acceleration changing it's value in time?

Tags: space-expansion

I understand that the cosmic acceleration (the acceleration of the expanding Universe) is estimated to have a value of something like $10^{-15} m/sec^2/Mpsec$.

My question is: how much this value changed and will change in time? What was the value of the cosmic acceleration 1 million, 1 billion, 5 billion and 10 billions of years ago?
What's the estimated value of the cosmic acceleration 1 million, 1 billion, 5 billion and 10 billions of years from now on?

Is this value constant or it changes in time?

Comment: Recent research suggests the expansion may not be accelerating at all, [source](https://www.space.com/34503-universe-expansion-accelerating-dark-energy.html).

Comment: @Joe Jobs.  Careful, the number you refer to I believe is from my answer to a previous question of yours, but the units were $m/sec^2/Mpsec$. It also was approximate, and the multiply arithmetic may be slightly off. And I used acceleration not as the acceleration parameter which is q, which is actually dimensionless. You'd have to define what acceleration was computed as. Or you may want to ask how and if q is changing: it is changing. I compuTed  d/dt$(\dot{a})$/a. And there could have been some arithmetic errors.